# Picking the array with the highest mean

Tags: python, max, python-xarray

Using xarray, I can define a 3D array:

```
>>> array = xr.DataArray(
[[[3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3]], [[1, 3, 2], [2, 5, 1], [2, 3, 1]]],
dims=("x", "y", "z"))

>>> array
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 3, z: 3)>
    array([[[3, 2, 1],
            [3, 1, 2],
            [2, 1, 3]],
           [[1, 3, 2],
            [2, 5, 1],
            [2, 3, 1]]])
    Dimensions without coordinates: x, y, z
```

From this 3D array, I want to pick the 2D array layer with highest mean of values.

I tried this:

```
max_layer = array.max(dim='x')
```

This does not work. Python creates a new 2D array with highest values along the x axis instead of doing what I want.

```
>>> max_layer
<xarray.DataArray (y: 3, z: 3)>
    array([[3, 3, 2],
           [3, 5, 2],
           [2, 3, 3]])
    Dimensions without coordinates: y, z
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want to find the mean along the `x` dimension?

Comment: No, I want to pick the 2D array with the highest mean of values located somewhere in the x axis. Imagine you have a stack of paper and there are arrays printed on them. You want to take out the paper sheet with the array with the highest mean of values. That is why I tried the .max() function because I thought it would estimate the 2D array with the highest mean of values and pick it for the new dataarray variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max` atrribute does not automatically calculate the means. You have to take the mean of the 2D layers first and then use `argmax` to get the index of the 2D layer with the maximum mean.

```
import xarray as xr

array = xr.DataArray(
[[[3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3]], [[1, 3, 2], [2, 5, 1], [2, 3, 1]]],
dims=("x", "y", "z"))

# Get the means of the 2D layers from the `x` dimension
array_means = array.mean(dim = ['y', 'z'])

# Check the means
print(array_means)

<xarray.DataArray (x: 2)>
array([2.        , 2.22222222])

# Find the index of the 2D layer with the maximum mean
idx = array_means.argmax()

print(array[idx])

<xarray.DataArray (y: 3, z: 3)>
array([[1, 3, 2],
       [2, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 1]])
Dimensions without coordinates: y, z
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. This doesn't totally resolve my situation because I actually am working with a netcdf file that has month temperature mean 2D layers and I want to pick the index for the coldest months in a year, over a 30 year period. I have to figure out how to get all the indexes and then calculate the average temperature of the coldest months for that period.